# Scrolling Text with Transparent Background

Tags: java, animation, jlabel

I used to write a Tect Ticker ,but unfortunately im weak on Java and i should make this work on Linux so :
I need a JLabel which handles text and that text should move like a News Ticker ,it should scroll the text inside a JPanel from End to Being JPanel Bounds horizontally .

If anyone had this experience than i`ll appreciate sharing with me.

Cheers

**Update :**
I solved the problem by using this example [Java Translucent](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) and next using Vincent Ramdhanie example i could Animate it .

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at code of existing news ticker, like [jrsst](http://jrsst.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yup that's great ,but i need a Transparent (Translucent) one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a JPanel with a label that uses a simple thread to scroll some text. You can modify it to suit your needs.

```
 public class Scroller extends JPanel implements Runnable{
  JLabel label;
  String str = "The Message to Scroll ";

  public Scroller(){
    super();
    label = new JLabel(str);
    add(label);
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
  }

  public void run(){
    while(true){
        char c = str.charAt(0);
        String rest = str.substring(1);
        str = rest + c;
        label.setText(str);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
  }
 }
```

So you can place this on a JFrame to see it in action. Also the the string algorithm may not be optimal but it works.

Comment: It could be better if we Put a JLabel into a JPanel and JPanel to JFrame than move JLabel (change location inside a loop) from Right Bound to Left Bound ,but Translucent Background is very important